# ComboBox adds all the values together as one value

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jcombobox

I'm making an application at the moment and now I need to fill a comboBox with all the values that I get from another class in an arrayList type.

This is the code that I use to fill my combobox:

```
public void setComboBox(){
    MessageConsole mc = new MessageConsole(textArea);
    //The redirectOut will redirect the text from the System.out.prtnln to the text area.
    mc.redirectOut();
    List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    if(gf.loadCombo("config") != null){
    arrayList.addAll(gf.loadCombo("config"));
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
            String s = arrayList.get(i);
            configName.removeItem(s);
            configName.addItem(s);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code from the other class:

```
public Collection<String> loadCombo(String property) {
    //Check if the property file is present in the given directory.
    if(cf.checkProperty()==true){
        //Check is there are any properties saved in the property file.
        if(cf.getProperty() != null){
            Properties prop = new Properties();
            FileInputStream fis;
            try {
                fis = new FileInputStream("config.properties");
                prop.load(fis);

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //Check if the properties match with the entered configuration.
            List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
            arrayList.addAll(cf.getProperty());
            Collection<String> propertyList = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
                String s = arrayList.get(i);
                if(s.startsWith(property)){
                    System.out.println("This value has been added to the arrayList from the other class: "+s);
                    propertyList.add(cf.getPropertyValue(s));
                }
            }
            return propertyList;
        }

        //The system prints a message of the missing properties.
        else{
            System.out.println("You need to save a configuration first.");
        }
    }

    //The system prints a message of the missing property file.
    else{
        System.out.println("The property file is either missing or could not be found. in de Load class");
    }
    return null;
}
```

Following is a screenshot of the result:

[image]

As you can see all the values are added as 1 long String"[3, 2, 1]" in the comboBox. Could anyone tell me why this happens?

Thanks in advance,

Lordarnoud

P.S. I hope this is the correct way to ask my question and I hope my question is clear enough for everyone to understand.

Comment: Why do you remove then add an item? Also debug your loadCombo method at the return part and see if the "[3 2 1]" is in the list or not. If it is not there. This is the artifact of your approach in add and remove items in the combo box

Comment: please add a tag to clarify which ui framework you mean (looks like Swing?)

Comment: @Masood_Mj: I did this because otherwise the comboBox would just add the value and not replace the old value, this would cause for the value to appear twice in the comboBox.

Comment: @kleopatra: I didn't even think about that, thanks for pointing it out. It is indeed Swing. But DixonJ already helped me out. But thanks I'll keep this in mind should I ever have to ask a question again. It's too bad I am limited to the 5 tags restriction.

Comment: no offense meant, but ... your tag choosing needs a bit of polish :-) Neither return nor string is overly expressive, you might consider to remove both and add wwing instead. Plus it should be jcombobox (which hints to swing) instead of combobox (which is a generic term for ui framework. Just sayin' :-)

Comment: @kleopatra No offense taken :) And I see what you mean, I thought I should mention String because I thought the row of values was caused by returning or using too many Strings or something along those lines. Thanks for the advice :) Edited the tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a first look it appears the problem could be one of two things:

1. The value "[3 2 1]" is returned from the `loadCombo` method. More specifically from the `cf.getProperty()`. It is not clear from the context provided what `cf` is.
2. The value "[3 2 1]" was added to your combobox at some other point in you code. If this might be case, try using `configName.removeAllItems()` instead of removing then adding each item in your collection.

Additionally in your `loadCombo` method you load the config.properties file into a Properties object and then do nothing with it. It seems your intentions were to load the config properties from that file instead of the `cf` object.

Comment: Thanks for your replies everyone. The removeAllItems() did the trick!. Thanks for your clear comment @DixonJ. I can't believe I missed that method in the API... And you are right about the prop as well. I have so many methods that use the prop that I didn't even notice that this method has one but wasn't using it. Thanks a lot!